# displaying model in opengl

Tags: python, rendering, opengl

I am trying to depict the story of the thirsty crow using crow, pebbles and waterpitcher with different water levels in it. I have created a objects using blender. When i export these models and use them in my python script, i just get the solid outer layer of the pebble or the water pitcher. I am not able to get the textures or show different water layers in it. I have followed i video tutorial, according to which i have carried out all the steps perfectly. Can anyone help me with this? I need to apply texture on the pebble and show water level on the pitcher.[image: a half filled pitcher in blender is rendered black in opengl. According to me there is some issue with blender and not with openg]

Comment: Please elaborate, maybe some links. Eg what script, what tutorial?

Comment: Also, to make screenshots within blender you can press Ctrl+F3, then choose if you want to save the whole interface or just the active window.

Comment: batFINGER i will explain the entire proceduere here. First i made the blender object, to which i added material. I marked the seam, genereted the uv mapping and exported the uv layout. In paint i coloured the desired part as required. I then went on to textures in blender and opened the file which i cretaed in paint. Thats it!! The image got rendered. While exporting the .obj file i selected the followijg options....selections only, apply modifiers, triangulate faces, object as obj object, write materials, include edges, include uvs. Thus i could generate the obj file as well.